# Codeigniter Active Record Class Error vs MySQL Raw Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

In my **Model**, I wrote this function with **MySQL raw query**

```
function get_question_result($lr_id)
{
    $raw_query = 'SELECT question_record.qr_id, LEFT(question.question, 50) as question,
                    question.correct_answer
                    FROM question_record
                    INNER JOIN question ON question.q_id = question_record.q_id
                    WHERE question_record.lr_id = '.$lr_id.' ';
    $query = $this->db->query($raw_query);
    $questionresult = $query->result_array();
    return $questionresult;
}
```

It **worked** fine. It gave me the array I want. I continued my project.

Then suddenly I was curious to try it in CI **Active Record Class**.

```
function get_question_result($lr_id)
{
    $this->db->select('question_record.qr_id, LEFT(question.question, 50) as question, question.correct_answer');
    $this->db->from('question_record');
    $this->db->join('question', 'question.q_id = question_record.q_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('question_record.lr_id', $lr_id);
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

It didn't work. It gave me this **error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object
```

Just out of curiosity, where did I do wrong?
Was it me writing it wrong or the result data structure with Active Record is just different?

'cause when I tried it again in Active Record **without selecting** this field

```
LEFT(question.question, 50) as question
```

It **worked** but it didn't give the field I want. Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `$this->db->select()` call you need pass `FALSE` as second parameter so that active record will not try to add backticks ` for your columns in select statement

```
function get_question_result($lr_id)
{
    $this->db->select('question_record.qr_id, LEFT(question.question, 50) as question, question.correct_answer',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('question_record');
    $this->db->join('question', 'question.q_id = question_record.q_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('question_record.lr_id', $lr_id);
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

According to docs

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

[*`$this->db->select();`*](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: I tried it and it worked! I usually ignore the second parameter. This explains why Active Record mostly doesn't work when I use compound select query. So it was just my fault after all. Thanks a lot @MKhalidJunaid!